# How to close OpenCV automatically after the video finishes playing?

Tags: python, opencv

I need help. I want whenever my program reaches the end of the video, I want it to be closed automatically without looping for forever.

I've tried several methods (using ret) but they don't work. I'm not sure why it always went wrong other than I could've probably written them in the wrong scope.

I also need to record the elapsed time difference from the time I opened the video to the time the video closes (using `time.time()`). But, this code I wrote below didn't print out the time difference whenever I force closed the OpenCV window.

This is the rough structure of my code (not the full code, I only show the important ones):

```
import stuff

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('file.mp4')

def main():
    start = time.time()
    
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('newvid.mp4')

    while True:
        #Stuff I do on the video in each frame
        video = cap.copy()

        cv2.imshow('video', video)
        out.write(video)

        if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
            break

    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ = '__main__':
    main()
```

Can anyone help me and tell me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import stuff
import cv2
import time
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('file1.mp4')


def main():
    start = time.time()

    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V')
    fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
    size = (int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)), int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
    out = cv2.VideoWriter('newvid.mp4', fourcc, fps, size)

    while True:
        # Stuff I do on the video in each frame
        ret, video = cap.read()

        if ret is False:
            break
        cv2.imshow('video', video)
        out.write(video)

        if cv2.waitKey(33) == 27:
            break

    end = time.time()
    print(end - start)
    cap.release()
    out.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```